# Magento 1.9 inside wordpress folder gives 404 in product page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, http-status-code-404

I have a magento website inside Wordpress with the following structure:

- wordpress/magento

After migrating to local server I could put everything working perfectly, excepts the product page, that gives me 404 error.

I can access main page (wordpress), catalog page (magento) but **not product page (magento)**.

I notice that the main magento folder is stripped when I access product page.

**This is my catalog folder - OK**

> http://mystore/store/product-category

**When I try to access a product - 404 error**

> http://mystore/product-category/product

In this case, the htaccess strips the **store** folder.

I can imagine the error is on .htaccess file in magento root, but I don't know what is missing.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /mystore/store/

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I notice in my server log, that when I try to access a product, the server tries to access the following url:

```
http://localhost/store/catalog/product
```

When he should try to access:

```
http://localhost/mystore/store/catalog/product
```

I don't know where he is getting this

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the `base_url` and `secure_base_url`? Here is a way to change it: https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html

Also check the Rewrite Rule in .htaccess: #RewriteBase /mystore/store/